# JQgrid - Populate select filter toolbar search using xml datatype

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqgrid

I have JqGrid of type tree grid and I'm trying to populate select search in filter toolbar base the data from the server (the data that returned in **XML** format).
I found the functions that get unique values from specific rows and than build the string in the correct format (for example: ":All;1:1;2:2;3:3").

one of my grid option is `loadonce:true`, and what i understood from documentation is that if this option is set to `true` and i get the data from the server in XML or JSON format it change the datatype property to `local` automatically and all the changes that i want to perform is on the client side code.

here is what i was trying to do:

```
<script>                        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#treegrid").jqGrid({
            treeGrid: true,
            treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
            ExpandColumn: 'name',
            direction: 'rtl',
            url: 'Handlers/JQTreeGridDataHandler.ashx',// from here i'm getting the XML data from server and it works fine
            datatype: "xml",                                
            mtype: "POST",
            colNames: ["id", "Account", "Acc Num", "Debit", "Credit", "Balance"],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 1, hidden: true, key: true },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 180 },// this is the col that i want to add the select filter
                { name: 'num', index: 'acc_num', width: 80, align: "center", search: false },
                { name: 'debit', index: 'debit', width: 80, align: "right", search: false },
                { name: 'credit', index: 'credit', width: 80, align: "right", search: false },
                { name: 'balance', index: 'balance', width: 80, align: "right", search: false }
            ]
            height: 'auto',
            sortname: 'name',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            pager: "#ptreegrid",
            caption: "Treegrid example"
        });


        setSearchSelect.call($("#treegrid"), "name");                            

        $("#treegrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });

    });

    //Functions for Toolbar searching
    var getUniqueNames = function (columnName) {
        var t = $("#treegrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
            texts = $.map(t, function (item) { return item.name; }), uniqueTexts = [],
            textsLength = texts.length, text, textsMap = {}, i;
        for (i = 0; i < textsLength; i++) {
            text = texts[i] 
            if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
                // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
                textsMap[text] = true;
                uniqueTexts.push(text);
            }
        }
        return uniqueTexts;
    },
        buildSearchSelect = function (uniqueNames) {
            var values = ":All;";
            $.each(uniqueNames, function () {
                values += this + ":" + this + ";";
            });

            return values.slice(0, -1);
        },
        setSearchSelect = function (columnName) {
            $("#treegrid").jqGrid('setColProp', columnName,
                {
                    stype: "select",
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['eq'],
                        value: buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames.call($("#treegrid"), columnName))                                            
                    }
                });
        };
</script>
```

please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks a lot

Comment: It is unclear for me what is the problem? Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid ver <=4.7? What is the code in the function `setSearchSelect.call(...)`

Comment: I'm using jqGrid version 5.3.1, the function is   `setSearchSelect = function (columnName) {
            $("#treegrid").jqGrid('setColProp', columnName,
                {
                    stype: "select",
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['eq'],
                        value: buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames.call($("#treegrid"), columnName))                                            
                    }
                });` i already add this function in my first question (you can scroll down the code and you can see all other functions)

Comment: Again to ask - What is the problem - you can't build the search you can't build the select the search does not work....? Please describe!

Comment: Ok... 1)I can't build the search and the select (because I don't know where is the right place in code to call the `getUniqueNames` function). 2) after I done with getting the unique values how can I put those unique values in filter search that I can see them on the grid. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is due to the ajax call. To explain: You grid is created according to the grid options. And ajax call is made for the data. The data comes with delay according to your server response, amount of dat requested, network connections and etc. Untill the data com to the grid you call a finction to build a select based on the data, but the data is not present at the grid. To solve the proble you have two options

1.Use setTimeout to delay the creation of the select and serch like

```
...
setTimeout(function() {
    setSearchSelect.call($("#treegrid"), "name");                            
    $("#treegrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });
}, 800);
...
```

2.The second recommended way is to call these once when tha data is loaded. This can be accomplished in gridComplete event and a flag indicationg is the select is build. Below the code:

```
    var buildselect = false;
    jQuery("#treegrid").jqGrid({ 
        url: 'data.xml', 
        treedatatype: "xml", 
        mtype: "POST", 
        colNames:["id","Account","Acc Num", "Debit", "Credit","Balance","Enabled"], 
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:1,hidden:true,key:true}, 
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:180 }, 
            {name:'num',index:'acc_num', width:80, align:"center", search: false}, 
            {name:'debit',index:'debit', width:80, align:"right", search: false}, 
            {name:'credit',index:'credit', width:80,align:"right", search: false}, 
            {name:'balance',index:'balance', width:80,align:"right", search: false}, 
            {name:'enbl', index:'enbl', hidden: true} 
        ], 
        height:'auto', 
        pager : "#ptreegrid", 
        treeGrid: true, 
        loadonce : true,
        ExpandColumn : 'name', 
        caption: "Treegrid example",
        gridComplete : function() {
            if(!buildselect) {
                setSearchSelect.call($("#treegrid"), "name");                            
                $("#treegrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });
                buildselect = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is a working [demo of your code](http://guriddo.net/demo/treegridjs/searchxml/)